# Acer Aspire One, system slow. Graphics problem?

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, 32-bit, ubuntu-netbook, aspire-one

I have a Acer Aspire One

**Intel Atom CPU N280 1.66GHz**

**2gb RAM**

**Video:
Intel Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller**

It was running Windows Vista before, and was very slow. I tried to change to Ubuntu, but is even slower.

This computer is even certified in Ubuntu website:
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/200908-3469/

I installed the 32-bits as recomended for 2gb RAM.

The system works well, showing only problems in graphic parts, such as minimizing windows and opening the search window.

EDIT:
I have searched the forum and I have seen many similar problems. and believe that problems are the graphic drivers and / or graphic efects. None of the other questions helped

The System Monitor is is showing the CPU usage at 100% constantly

Comment: If you are using a slower, limited machine, you should consider using a variant of Ubuntu. I run Lubuntu 14.04 on an eeePC-900, a first generation netbook, and it's very usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computer is certified for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This does not mean that 14.04 will not work, however for better performance (more specifically Ubuntu Certified performance) it most likely will be best if you use 12.04.

12.04's release cycle and EOL can be seen [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). So you still have time to use Ubuntu, before you get a new laptop, or switch to a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Ubuntu would have issues with the Intel graphics but you could try the following:

- Change the desktop environment
- Disable startups

and more information can be found here :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997932

which also points to:

http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

First of all a couple words about distribution you download. According to the documentation for your CPU it's 32 Bit , that's why you download Ubuntu 32 bit. Most 32-bit OSes really only let individual applications use 2 GB of RAM, even if you have 4 GB installed. On the other hand if you would have 64bit CPU event with 2Gb of RAM you could install 64 bit OS for performance benefits.

However the machine you have is really slow, I tried myself Ubuntu on it and the slow things made me crazy. I tried it with SSD insead of HDD and that was a bit of change, I stopped waiting for ages. So it's where we are, you can also get performance increase on it with SSD.